# Codeigniter 2x : Show PDF and Download Excel on Nginx

Tags: excel, codeigniter, pdf, nginx

I have a website by Codeigniter 2x very old. I tested on local (Mamp) then everything ok, but when I deployed on Nginx server ec2. I can not show the Pdf file on the Browser and can not download the Excel file.

could someone suggest for me about config for the Nginx server?

Here is my actual config for our website.

```
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the file you want to download is present in `/var/www/html/` directory? Can you try restarting nginx and check the logs when you try to access the pdf file?

Use: `sudo tail -f -n 20 /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: thanks , I see now the errors on Dompdf library .I try to fix it right now

Comment: My Php7.1 needs php-mbstring. After I installed it , pdf file word well on server. I forgot to check logs and feel stupid myself